# Cannot make it work sith Shibboleth SP configuration for site id =2

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth

I have a very simple problem I cannot fix and I feel stupid.
I am trying to run Shibboleth SP3 for SSO for a website hosted by IIS.

I configure a sample website 1, under IIS, with an index.aspx.

I configured the ISAPI and RequestMap as follow:

```
<InProcess logger="native.logger">
    <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true">           
    <Site id="1" name="localhost" scheme="http" port="80"/>
    </ISAPI>    
</InProcess>
<RequestMapper type="Native">
    <RequestMap>
        <Host name="localhost">
           <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" />
</RequestMap>
```

It works well, I am redirected to the Idp, my claims are extracted. Now I want to use a another site in IIS, with id 2.  Here is my configuration:

```
<InProcess logger="native.logger">
    <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true">           
    <Site id="2" name="localhost" scheme="http" port="81"/>
    </ISAPI>    
</InProcess>
<RequestMapper type="Native">
    <RequestMap>
        <Host name="localhost">
           <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" />
</RequestMap>
```

The id matches the site id on IIS. I remove the configuration of the first site to avoid problem at this stage.
Now, after restarting IIS and shib_default service, when I type http://localhost:81/secure/index.html, I am not redirected to my IDP.

Why ? Is there anything I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to secure two different localhost http listeners, and I don't think that's supported. The way I would do this, is add `site1.dev` and `site2.dev` to your hosts file, and alter the IIS configuration so that site1.dev is asserted as the hostname for site #1, and vice versa.

Then, your shibboleth configuration will look something like this:

```
<InProcess logger="native.logger">
    <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true">
        <Site id="1" name="site1.dev" scheme="http" port="80"/>           
        <Site id="2" name="site2.dev" scheme="http" port="80"/>
    </ISAPI>    
</InProcess>
<RequestMapper type="Native">
    <RequestMap>
        <Host name="site1.dev">
           <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" />
        </Host>
        <Host name="site2.dev">
           <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" />
        </Host>
    </RequestMap>
</RequestMapper>
```

Basically, things get weird if you're trying to run HTTP on non-standard ports (81) with Shib. I've never seen anyone do that, even in a development environment. And no matter what, you can't have multiple `<InProcess>`, `<ISAPI>`, and `<RequestMapper>` elements.

Edit: I think you might even need to define multiple ApplicationOverrides for what you're doing.

Comment: Actually I manage to make it run, but if you use a different port, you also need to specify it in the RequestMap. The 'Host' tag also supports port attribute, and it needs to be specified there to match the port specified in the ISAPI filter.